# "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use Google Spreadsheets but I get this error when an ARRAYFORMULA would overwrite some rows of cells that already has something in them.

"Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data"

Is there a way to force an overwrite?

Comment: You have clear data to existing cell.

Comment: Is there a way to force an overwrite not clear?

Comment: Only AppScript can over write but formula can't.